# How to generate a random number of specific figures?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a small haskell game that generates a random number of 3 digits, and then the user tries to guess it in x amount of tries, my problem is, i know how to generate random numbers in haskell, but i dont know how to make that random number to be of a specific lenght, example, generate only random numbers than consist of 3 digits like 334,554,998,342 or 348.
Any tips or start points?
Will be much apreciated.

Comment: Well what method are you using to generate random numbers?  Most methods allow you to generate within a range naturally.  Other methods generate random byte, which you can simply take in 10 bit chunks and step over till you find a value in a small enough range.

Comment: `randomR (100, 999)`. See the [`System.Random` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just generate a random number in the range 100–999, for example with `randomR :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => (a, a) -> g -> (a, g)` with an explicit generator, or `randomRIO :: Random a => (a, a) -> IO a` to use the global generator.

If you want to allow numbers with a zero prefix, like `001`, you can generate a number in the range 0–999, then if you need to extract the individual digits for comparison, you can do so with `div` and `mod`:

```
do
  number <- randomRIO (0, 999)
  let
    hundreds = number `div` 100
    tens = (number `div` 10) `mod` 10
    ones = number `mod` 10
  …
```

Alternatively, you can simply generate three random digits:

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)

f = do
  d1 <- randomDigit
  d2 <- randomDigit
  d3 <- randomDigit
  let number = 100 * d1 + 10 * d2 + d3
  …
  where
    randomDigit = randomRIO (0, 9)
```

You can factor out the repetition using something like `replicateM :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`, for example if you want to make the number of digits into a parameter:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random (randomRIO)

f n = do
  ds <- replicateM n randomDigit
  let number = digitsToInt ds
  …
  where
    randomDigit = randomRIO (0, 9)
    digitsToInt = foldl ((+) . (10 *)) 0
```